# How can I post the score on the FB / Gmail / etc?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

How Can we achieve the functionality of post  the score or image on social networking sites or somewhere else ?

In android uploading the photos used "Sharing Intent " . What is the way to do the same thing in cocos2d android because I have not seen any tutorial on web.

Anyone suggest , What is needed for it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to show score , Image or both ?

Comment: both if it is possible ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called SocialAuth for android. It can be used in cocos2d, as i used it in my games.

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Comment: there is nothing to elaborate here actually. download this [link](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/detail?name=socialauth-android-sdk-2.6.zip&can=2&q=) and you get 4 examples in it. put anyone of the example in your code. its simple as that. just copy paste. enjoy